# How to plot distribution of final grade by sex?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm working on predicting student performance based on various different factors. This is a link to my data: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance#. This is a sample of the observations from the sex and final grade data columns:

```
sex G3
F   6
F   6
F   10
F   15
F   10
M   15
M   11
F   6
M   19
M   15
F   9
F   12
M   14
```

**I'm looking at the distribution of my target variable (final grade):**

```
ax= sns.kdeplot(data=df2, x="G3", shade=True)
ax.set(xlabel= 'Final Grade', ylabel= 'Density', title= 'Distribution of Final Grade')
plt.xlim([0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Screenshot of Distribution of Final Grade

[image]

And now I want to find out how the distribution of final grades differ by sex:
How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example following an [appropriate guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also, have you looked at the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the sample data.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['F','F','F','F','F','M','M','F','M','M','F','F','M'], 'grades': [6,6,10,15,10,15,11,6,19,15,9,12,14]})
```

```
sex G3
F   6
F   6
F   10
F   15
F   10
M   15
M   11
F   6
M   19
M   15
F   9
F   12
M   14
```

We use the [seaborn countplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) as follows.

```
sns.countplot(x="grades", hue='sex', data=df2)
```

To get the following plot.

[image]